# C++ How to check last value in line and replace line if it is more than a certain value

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, stl

I want to replace a line of a file, but only if the 3rd (last) value is above `0.000000`.

Specifically I have an Ascii .stl file, like below, where I want to be able to check the last value of each `vertex` line, and replace the entire line with a different string if it is above `0.000000`.
I am really struggling with understanding how to create a parser using regex, to look for this. I also don't know if that's the best way.

Any help with the parsing would be very much appreciated.

```
facet normal -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
outer loop
vertex 26.000000 6.000000 0.000000
vertex 26.000000 6.000000 1.000000
vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
endloop
endfacet
facet normal -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
outer loop
vertex 26.000000 6.000000 0.000000
vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
vertex 26.000000 7.000000 0.000000
endloop
endfacet
facet normal 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
outer loop
vertex 26.000000 7.000000 0.000000
vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
vertex 27.000000 7.000000 1.000000
endloop
endfacet
endsolid
```

If it matters, I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Here's a good place for experimenting: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Honestly, this really doesn't need any use of regex to solve. --*and replace the entire line with a different string* -- What is this "different string"?  And where does the replacement go?  In a new file?  We need more details.

Comment: The different string is another set of coordinates, formatted the same. The replacement would probably just write over that line of the file, or amend it in a new file. I assume I could work that out. I don't need my question given a finished solution; I'm fine with just being told words I can use to find what I need to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something as simple as detecting which line starts with "vertex", I don't think you need something as heavy as a regular expression.

Here is a very simple example of detecting the line that starts with "vertex":

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string test = "facet normal -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "outer loop\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 6.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 6.000000 1.000000\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000\n"
                    "endloop\n"
                    "endfacet\n"
                    "facet normal -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "outer loop\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 6.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 7.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "endloop\n"
                    "endfacet\n"
                    "facet normal 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "outer loop\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 7.000000 0.000000\n"
                    "vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000\n"
                    "vertex 27.000000 7.000000 1.000000\n"
                    "endloop\n"
                    "endfacet\n"
                    "endsolid";
                    
int main()
{
    std::istringstream strm(test);
    std::string line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while (std::getline(strm, line))
    {
        ++lineNumber;
        if (line.compare( 0, 6, "vertex", 6) == 0) // check if line starts with "vertex"
        {
            std::istringstream strm2(line);  // read the line
            std::string type;
            double num1, num2, num3;
            strm2 >> type >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
            if ( num3 > 0 )  // checks the last number
                std::cout << "Line " << lineNumber << ": " << line << "\n";  // just outputs that line
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line 4: vertex 26.000000 6.000000 1.000000
Line 5: vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
Line 11: vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
Line 18: vertex 26.000000 7.000000 1.000000
Line 19: vertex 27.000000 7.000000 1.000000
```

In lieu of a file, the code reads the data from a stringstream.

It's just a matter of detecting the line that starts with `"vertex"`, and then using a [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to read the data.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! I never knew I could do it like this; it will definitely help with future simple parsing like this. I now have a working program that takes standard files.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the comments of others that Regex may not be the best approach depending on the nature of your solution. But for a Regex to find what you're after:

```
vertex.+\s[0-9\.]*[1-9][0-9\.]*$
```

Should do the trick.
([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E2ALjg/2))

Comment: Thank you for this; I did see separating the decimal in two, but I never got it to work. I will definitely play around with it more in regex101 to try to understand it

Comment: My pleasure @Jack.